# Removing jQuery small boilerplate

Tags: jquery, optimization, boilerplate

this is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('td').empty();
        getWeather();
    });

    $('.data').change(function() {
        $('td').empty();
        getWeather();
    });
```

How can I optimize it?

I was thinking of using "OR", but I couldn't fit it anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about...

```
var f = function() {
  $('td').empty();
  getWeather();
}

$(document).ready(f);
$('.data').change(f);
```

Comment: I know its obvious :) but you will not have to make duplicate changes when you need to edit function "f". as well as the fact that you will be able to call it from other places in the future.